# Valor de variable cambia con respecto al original en método

Tags: java

Resulta que estoy tratando de implementar la heurística *Simulated Annealing*. Pero tengo un problema, ya que al entregarle un arreglo (`sol`) a un método (`neighbor`), el valor del arreglo cambia al original. Es decir, la variable `sol` no es la misma luego de entregársela al arreglo.

El método es el siguiente:

```
public static int[] neighbor(int sol[]) {  //Función que genera un vvecino de la solución
    System.out.println("1: "+ cost(sol));
    int aux[];  //Será el arreglo que corresponde al parámetro recibido o la solución de las 8 reinas
    int auxN;   //Variable auxiliar que permite guardar el elemento que será intercambiado
    int azar1;  //Se genera esta variable para guardar la posición del elemento que se intercambiará
    int azar2;  //Se genera esta variable para guardar la posición del elemento que será intercambiado

    aux = sol;    //Se inicializa el arreglo igualandolo a la solución recibida por el método
    azar1=(int) (Math.random()*7);  //Se generan números aleatorios entre 1 y 8, corresponde a la posición del elemento que se intercambiará
    azar2=(int) (Math.random()*7);  //Se generan números aleatorios entre 1 y 8, corresponde a la posición del elemento que se intercambiará

    System.out.println("2: "+ cost(sol));

    while (azar1==azar2){           //Mientras las variables sean iguales se repetirá el proceso de elegir otro número al azar, ya que al ser iguales no se pueden intercambar
        azar2=(int) (Math.random()*7);
    }

    auxN=aux[azar1];     //El elemento de la posición azar1 es guardado en la variable 
    aux[azar1]=aux[azar2];  //El elemento de la posición azar1 es intercambiado por el elemento de la posición azar2

    System.out.println("3: "+ cost(sol));
    aux[azar2]=auxN;     //El elemento de la posición azar2 es intercambiado por el elemento de la posición azar1 (guardado en auxN)
    System.out.println("4: "+ cost(sol));

    return aux;          //Se devuelve el arreglo con las variables ya intercambiadas

}
```

Cabe decir que puse los `System.out.println` para que notaran cuándo cambia el valor del arreglo que se le entrega al método, y además decir que el método `cost` calcula el costo del arreglo (de realizar la ruta indicada por éste).

El resultado es este:

```
1: 5752.0
2: 5752.0
3: 6061.0
4: 5721.0
```

Todo indica que, al cambiar el valor de la variable `aux` cambia el de `sol`, pero no sé cómo evitar esto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto es debido a que los tipos de datos como los array, son tipos de datos que se pasan por referencia, es decir que hacen referencia a la misma posición de memoria, al realizar la asignación `aux = sol` estas diciendo que `aux` apunte a la misma posición de memoria de `sol` motivo por el cual cada vez que realizas un cambio en `aux` también cambias `sol`. La solución a esto es realizar un copy del array, el cual puedes hacer con un `for`

```
int[] aux = new int[sol.length];
for(int i = 0; i < sol.length; i++){
  aux[i] = sol[i];
}
```

O puedes usar la función copyOf de la clase Arrays

```
int[] aux = Arrays.copyOf(sol, sol.length);
```